# multiple input validation constraints? c++

Tags: c++, validation, input

I have to make sure the letters input consists only of **M, D, C, L, X, V, and I**, which I have done.

My problem is that they are *Roman numerals*, and I have to also make sure that if a lower value character precedes a higher value character, it follows the rules of Roman numerals:

- **M, D, C** can be preceded by a character 2 spots lower so `CM` or `DM` is okay, but `LM` is not.
- **L, X, V** can only be preceded by a character 1 spot lower so `XL` is okay, but `VL` is not.

The 7 letters represent values as follows:

```
╔════════╦═══════╗
║ Symbol ║ Value ║
╠════════╬═══════╣
║ I      ║ 1     ║
║ V      ║ 5     ║
║ X      ║ 10    ║
║ L      ║ 50    ║
║ C      ║ 100   ║
║ D      ║ 500   ║
║ M      ║ 1,000 ║
╚════════╩═══════╝
```

This is what I have thus far:

```
void romanType::storeRoman()
{
    locale loc;
    bool valid = true;

    do
    {
        valid = true;
        cout << "please enter a roman numeral using no spaces:" << endl;
        getline(cin, rNums);

        for (i = 0; i < rNums.length(); ++i)
        {
            rNums[i] = toupper(rNums[i], loc);
            if (rNums[i] == 'M' || rNums[i] == 'D' || rNums[i] == 'C' ||
                rNums[i] == 'L' || rNums[i] == 'X' || rNums[i] == 'V' ||
                rNums[i] == 'I')
            {
                continue;
            }
            valid = false;
        }

        cout << "input error please try again\n" << endl;
    } while (!valid);

    /* ... */

}
```

It works as long as all the characters are Roman numerals, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to implement the other 2 constraints I mentioned. I got most of the rest of the program written, but I have spent probably 6-7 hours trying to get this one part too work. Please help.

Comment: Please format your code in some way a person could read it. Being formatted completely randomly seems to be a common trait of code here the owner does not understand.

Comment: Well, put the defined numeral characters in an array, in proper sequence, then match your input characters and do some relative comparisions based on the index.

Comment: Those are some very strange requirements, wouldn't they make certain numbers unenterable?

Comment: Hah, I hadn't thought about VL being incorrect (and XLV being the "proper" choice, as it seems to be.)

Comment: to mooing duck: no that's just how they work.

Comment: regexes to the rescue?

Comment: thanks for the edits, it looks much better then when I wrote it. Tim I don't know what regexes are.

Comment: I would have thought IX was a pretty standard Roman numeral, while VX (which your rules allow) simply doesn’t make sense. OTOH, your rules don’t disallow VV or IIIII, which I'm pretty sure are usually prohibited.

Comment: @user2087867 count yourself lucky then :)

Answer (score 2):

Following your rules, the *valid roman number* `MCMLIV` (1954) would be considered invalid as e.g. `C` can't be preceded by `M` and `L` can't be preceded by `M`. Your rules are thus wrong or incomplete.

However if you instead use these rules (taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals)) then it will work:

- The numeral `I` can be placed before `V` and `X` to make 4 units (`IV`) and 9 units (`IX`) respectively
- `X` can be placed before `L` and `C` to make 40 (`XL`) and 90 (`XC`) respectively
- `C` can be placed before `D` and `M` to make 400 (`CD`) and 900 (`CM`) according to the same pattern.

Now, your function basically needs to perform two things:

1. Check for invalid characters (only `IVXLCDM` are allowed)
2. Check that the above rules apply.

Your function does the first, but it can be simplified. All we want to do is to find any invalid character in the string. We can check that all characters are valid using [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

```
// The string representing a roman number.
std::string s = "MCMLIV";

// Check that the predicate is true for all elements in range.
const std::string allowedChars = "IVXLCDM";
bool valid = std::all_of(std::begin(s), std::end(s), [&allowedChars] (char c) {
    return allowedChars.find(::toupper(c)) != std::string::npos;
});

if (!valid) {
    std::cerr << "Input error" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Then we need to check the characters in pairs according to the rules. We can use [`std::adjacent_find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) for this:

```
// Check if we can find any pair that does not comply to the rules.
auto it = std::adjacent_find(std::begin(s), std::end(s), [] (char lhs, char rhs)
{
    lhs = std::toupper(lhs); // Transform to upper case.
    rhs = std::toupper(rhs); // Transform to upper case.
    return ((lhs == 'I' && rhs != 'V') && (lhs == 'I' && rhs != 'X')) ||
           ((lhs == 'X' && rhs != 'L') && (lhs == 'X' && rhs != 'C')) ||
           ((lhs == 'C' && rhs != 'D') && (lhs == 'C' && rhs != 'M'));
});

if (it != std::end(s)) {
    std::cerr << "Input error" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

That's it! See this [**live example**](http://ideone.com/fAmi6i).

**Edit:**

You will also have to check that `I` does not occur more than 3 times consecutively, so not to accept strings as `IIIIIII`. This should be fairly easy though.

Comment: I believe these rules are incomplete and IIIIIIIIIIIIIIII should not be accepted.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig The rules say "to make 4 units (IV) and 9 units (IX)" which can be interpreted as a restriction of the number of `I`'s that is allowed. I added an edit about it though, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

One approach (from a C mindset) might be to list the legal characters, and legal "offsets" (defined below) corresponding to them:

```
#define LEGALCHAR 7 // number of possible legal letters in roman numerals   
char legalValues[LEGALCHAR] = {'I', 'V', 'X', 'L', 'C', 'D', 'M'};
int allowedDelta[LEGALCHAR] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2};
```

and create an `int IndexedNumeral` array that contains the indices from `legalValues` of the matching character, e.g. MMX would be {6, 6, 2}.  Then loop over the 2nd through last entries of `IndexedNumeral` to compare the difference between the (`i-1`, `i`)th characters to the legal offset permitted by the `i`th character.

```
diff = indexedNumeral[i] - indexedNumeral[i-1];
if (diff > allowedDelta[indexedNumeral[i]]) {
  printf("illegal sequence: %i %i or  %c %c\n", indexedNumeral[i-1], indexedNumeral[i], argv[1][i-1], argv[1][i]);
  return 1;
}
```

There are certainly other approaches.